# to.period returns error attempt to set index 4/4 in SET_STRING_ELT in R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am a newbie with R and have been following a tutorial from YouTube by [Chris Reeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71etHJK_6Jo&list=UU3IcEolPgWzJzKl38XMP99w)
I am using xts with to.period to create OHLC from tick/second data.

My code

```
Last = AAPL.Last
Bid = AAPL.Bid
Ask = AAPL.Ask

colnames(Last) = c("TimeStamp","Price","Size")
colnames(Bid) = c("TimeStamp","Price","Size")
colnames(Ask) = c("TimeStamp","Price","Size")

Last$TimeStamp = strptime(Last$TimeStamp, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
Bid$TimeStamp = strptime(Bid$TimeStamp, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
Ask$TimeStamp = strptime(Ask$TimeStamp, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")

require("xts")
xtsLast = as.xts(Last$Price,order.by=Last$TimeStamp,frequency=NULL)
xtsAsk = as.xts(Ask$Price,order.by=Ask$TimeStamp,frequency=NULL)
xtsBid = as.xts(Bid$Price,order.by=Bid$TimeStamp,frequency=NULL)

require("quantmod")
chartSeries(xtsLast)

bars = to.period(xtsLast,
                 period = "seconds",
                 k=60,
                 indexAt = "startof",
                 name = NULL,
                 OHLC = TRUE):
require("quantmod")
chartSeries(bars)
```

The error that is returned is:

> Error in to.period(xtsLast, period = "seconds", k = 60, indexAt =
>   "startof",  :    attempt to set index 4/4 in SET_STRING_ELT

I have googled an answer but I am unable to get a complete answer so hence asking it here.  I apologize if this a very basic question.

I am working Windows 7 using RStudio with  Rx64 3.1.1.

Thanks,
H

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) the error, which makes it very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you don't set `name = NULL`.

```
require(quantmod)
base_url <- "http://www.reevesresearch.com/codes/TickDataAAPL/"
Last <- read.table(paste0(base_url, "AAPL.Last.txt"), sep=";")
colnames(Last) <- c("TimeStamp","Price","Size")
Last$TimeStamp <- strptime(Last$TimeStamp, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
xtsLast <- xts(Last$Price, order.by=Last$TimeStamp)
bars <- to.minutes(xtsLast, k=1, indexAt="startof")
```

Comment: Now fixed as of r859 on R-forge, so specifying `name = NULL` will work.

Comment: Thank you Joshua - I will remember to add more detail in future.  
Your advice has done the trick, however I was using to.periods and not to.minutes.  Is there a problem with to.periods?

Comment: @AlgoTraderNew: `to.minutes` is just a wrapper around `to.period`, so there's nothing wrong with `to.period`.